# Can I join another clan and help with the clan chest?

Tags: clash-royale

This question is about the Clash Royale clan chests, specifically the 2v2 clan battle chest.

> **! Note !** Clan chests were removed in April of 2018, replaced by the Clan War feature. This question is obsolete.

My understanding of the original clan chest based on crowns earned from battle is that the crowns only count for members who joined before the clan chest event began. So if I join a friends clan to win crowns for their chest after completing my own clan's chest, it won't count. Is this correct?

What happens in the 2v2 battles? If I battle with my friend who's been their since before the event began, does it count as a full win? A half win? Or not count at all?

If I battle with another person who wasn't there at the start of the event, do those wins count at all?

Comment: This question may be out of date forever. 2v2 Clan chests look like they're never coming back, deprecated in favor of regular clan chests with permanent 2v2 mode enabled.

Comment: I'm closing this question as it pertains to outdated mechanics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this out with the latest 2v2 battle lasting April 7th - 9th. After my clan reached 250 wins I and opened the 10/10 chest, I went to my friends clan. Battles played and with members who were in that clan before the event began still counted as full wins towards their chest. My contribution of 0.5 wins per won battle showed at the bottom of the clan list as 'Not part of this Clan Battle Chest'. Also, after leaving a clan, my participation was deleted from the list, masking how active I had been for any battle.

I was not able to test playing with another member who was not in the clan at the start of the battle.

I also have not tested what happens during the crown clan chest event.

As OldBunny2800 pointed out, you are never able to open a second clan chest.